# CloudPagesURL() causing error in Email Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

We are building a custom preference center that will be accessed via a link in an email built in SFMC Email Studio. We have the following in the anchor tag of the link in the email 
`<a href="%%=CloudPagesURL(1016)=%%">Update Preferences`
When we go to send the email we get an error: 
`invalid function call: CloudPagesURL([1016]). Attribute or Field Name: 1016. Invalid Content`

I know that the Cloud Page IS published and can be accessed if I paste the URL into a browser. I need to pass the subscriber context, jobID and batchID to later make a LogUnsubEvent call.

I have scoured docs and forums. Anyone have any ideas? is there something on the account that needs to be turned on, maybe??[image]

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the ID is the correct one?

Comment: @garek007 it was the 1st thing I did

Comment: I'd put in a support request, seems like something may not be provisioned in your account.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Web Analytics Connector (WAC) enabled in your account?  I've ran into issues calling Cloud Pages in accounts with this enabled.

As a work-around, try wrapping the [CloudPagesURL()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) function with [RedirectTo()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirectto.htm).

example:

```
%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1016))=%%
```